# Bad yet good framerate after exporting through Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, framerate, adobe-media-encoder

Lately, I've been getting a weird issue with my Media Encoder exports.

I usually import 2 files through After Affects CC: an "intro" one and the main movie, both at lossless quality, and export the result to an YouTube-compliant format.

Here are their format:

*File 1*:

```
Format                      : RGB
Codec ID                    : 0x00000000
Codec ID/Info               : Basic Windows bitmap format. 1, 4 and 8 bpp versions are palettised. 16, 24 and 32bpp contain raw RGB samples
Duration                    : 12s 12ms
Bit rate                    : 663 Mbps
Width                       : 1 280 pixels
Height                      : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate                  : 29.970 fps
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 24.000
```

*File 2*:

```
Format                      : Lagarith
Codec ID                    : LAGS
Duration                    : 9mn 20s
Bit rate                    : 106 Mbps
Width                       : 1 280 pixels
Height                      : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate                  : 29.970 fps
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 3.847
```

Once the composition is finished, I export the result through Media Encoder using this preset: **YouTube HD 720p 29,97**. And it works. At least it used to.

Now, I can clearly see ME still processing something at the end of the first-pass, even though everything's been done.
And the result after the second-pass is a video with a proper framerate that looks like it was encoded with a wrong one as the video plays faster than it should (I can clearly tell as it is out-of-sync with the audio), despite me using settings that look like correct.

Something goes wrong during the encoding, but I don't know what. Haven't tweaked the preset and I'm doing the exact same process as before.